# Can I make an exception in Task.Run crash the program?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

I'm not a big fan of quietly swallowed exceptions, but the following code does exactly that:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var obj = DoSomethingCpuIntensive(); // returns null, due to a bug
    obj.DoMoreStuff();
    Console.WriteLine("after"); // never get here; program continues running
});
```

I've read about the [ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj160346.aspx) configuration value, but this doesn't help, since I never do anything with the `Task` returned (edit: actually it does help, but only in Release builds).

Is there a way to make that unhandled exception crash the program? Am I using `Task.Run` in a way I'm not supposed to?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will crash your program when the task is garbage collected

Comment: you should not throw a new Exception object, use one of the derived classes like ApplicationException, SecurityException etc. your question is interesting, usually I need to make extra effort to avoid the whole program to crash when a task / thread throws an exception, now you have all of that already in place and still want the task to crash everything...

Comment: @DavidePiras That was just an example. I've made it clearer.

Comment: @JohanLarsson I added a GC.Collect() a few seconds after this `Task.Run` call. No crash of any kind. I should mention I'm on .NET 4.5.

Comment: Please note that GC.Collect is just a recommendation for garbage collection, it does not actually force it. And there are plenty of things to know about, e.g. generations in garbage collection etc

Comment: If you are on 4.5 you can check out [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx), I have not used it enough to give any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that using `Task.Run` like this is, indeed, a mistake. I think I'm supposed to `await` it, else silly things like the above will happen.

When it does crash with the `await`, the debugger is rather unhelpful, looking like this:

[image]

I take this all to mean I'm really doing the wrong thing with `Task.Run` here.

A simple fix is use the good old `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` instead:

[image]

That's much better! I didn't really need async/await in this code anyway; I just used `Task.Run` because it's less typing.

Comment: @Timwi It's almost the same; `Task.Run` is a shorthand for `StartNew` with some parameters set to defaults.

Comment: I'm following your approach but it is a shame that the new libraries work worse than the previous ones ...

Comment: Ey, I found how to do it using tasks. Please check the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856784/how-to-make-an-application-crash-when-a-task-throws-an-exception-without-waiting/27863178#27863178

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you use `Task.Run` over `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

First, take a step back. What's the purpose of `DoSomethingCpuIntensive`? If you're calculating some value, I suggest you return it, so you have a `Task<T>` instead of a `Task`. e.g., (assuming `DoMoreStuff` is not CPU intensive):

```
async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
  var obj = await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingCpuIntensive());
  obj.DoMoreStuff();
}
```

The idea I'm trying to get across is that your code *should* care about the results of your background operations, even if the "result" is just "success" or "exception". Your code is cleaner that way. Otherwise, you've got a semi-independent system that you can only respond to by detecting changes in your application state. Much more messy.

That said, if you really do want to have the semi-independent system and you want it to crash your process if it fails, then `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` is exactly what you want. I'm not sure why you think it wouldn't help.

Comment: I think you missed the whole point. Even if you move the `obj.DoMoreStuff` outside of the task, the problem still exists inside `DoSomethingCpuIntensive`. [Never assume that any part of the code cannot possibly throw](http://i.imgur.com/7xPKTxg.png) :)

Comment: My point is that if you do it this way, it doesn't matter where it throws. The exception is properly propagated back rather than directly crashing the process.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but there really do exist fire-and-forget tasks in programming... This task in particular does something CPU intensive and then saves it to the database. The caller doesn't care about the result, nor has anything at all to do with it.

Comment: Make sure you're putting a `Thread.Sleep` in your test code. [See Reed's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284137/taskscheduler-unobservedtaskexception-event-handler-never-being-triggered).

Comment: Apparently you also need to run a Release build. Debug builds don't do it. Reed's answer doesn't mention that, but MSDN on `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` does, in the Example section. How subtle. With this in mind, and everything I said before (about fire-and-forget, and having no answer to be returned), I really think `QueueUserWorkItem` is a much better fit. Do you have a specific reason why despite these shortcomings I should use `Task.Run`? (might be better as a separate question...)

Comment: If it is *truly* fire-and-forget, then `QueueUserWorkItem` is fine. I always avoid fire-and-forget; at the very least I prefer to take action on errors (and a global solution like `UnhandledTaskException` uglifies my design). So that's why I recommend `Task.Run` in general: if there's a result, or an error, or you want to cancel it, or report progress, or synchronize the result/error/progress, then `Task` is superior. But if you are absolutely sure you don't want to report errors, and you just want to crash instead, then `QueueUserWorkItem` is a perfect fit. It makes it *easy* to crash! ;)

Comment: Understood, thanks. I prefer a truly global solution like `AppDomain`s `UnhandledException`, with special-purpose handling for when I'm sure I can recover reliably or have specific additional details to log. Although in this particular case it was a throw-away single-use program which wasted me half an hour by pretending to do something instead of crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you've read about [`ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj160346.aspx); have you actually tried running your program with `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` set to `true` in your config?

The default behaviour in .NET 4 is that unobserved `Task` exceptions will bring down the entire process.

The default behaviour in .NET 4.5 is that unobserved `Task` exceptions *will not* bring down the process. Since you're running on .NET 4.5, setting `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` to `true` should do exactly what you require.

Comment: Yes, I have. Have you tried running my example with it set to true? It _does not throw_. It only throws if you `await` the `Task.Run`.

Comment: @romkyns: Yes, I have tried it and it *does* throw for me when `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` is enabled. (VS2012, .NET 4.5)

Comment: I got it. MSDN documents that this only happens in Release mode. Call me bitter, but how useful is that! :)

Comment: @romkyns: completely agree with that. This behavior should be configurable by the developer.