# How to make an application crash when a Task throws an exception without waiting the finalizer

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, task

We are using Tasks in our .Net 4 (no async await available) application and sometimes they are used to launch 'Fire and Forget' operations  like the following one:

```
private void Test()
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Test");
    });
}
```

We want this exception to crash the application without waiting the task (as otherwise it makes no sense to have it in a task, at least in our scenarios) and without waiting the finalizer as we want to shutdown the application when an unexpected error happens to avoid state corruptions (we are saving the state present when the exception happened).

My guess is that somehow we should work with a continuation task but that puts the continuation code inside another task that will not make the application crash so I'm blocked here.

Any help will be very appreciated

**Edit:** if switching to the ThreadPool the result is the expected one. The following code crashes the application:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Test");
});
```

Comment: `await` the Task and get notified about the exceptions?

Comment: Why are you firing off tasks which can cause your application to crash without properly handling them? Is this really a valid design choice in your opinion?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: we are working with .Net 4 so we don't have this option :( Edited for clarity.

Comment: @SoMoS If you have VS2012, you can use async/await with .Net4.0 using [BCL.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: we have global handlers for unexpected exceptions and we need to use them.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather assign a continuation which handles those exceptions instead of queuing those tasks for finalization and waiting for the finalizer to fire them at any given time?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Long story short: if we have an unexpected exception (which means we have a bug, otherwise it is not unexpected) we want to crash the application and save the current state. To do that we use global handlers. We cannot handle these exceptions as we don't know which ones will be fired.

Comment: Once a task fails with any exception, is that a sign that you should crash the application?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: good to know but seems that it is only for Windows8 applications :\ Am I right?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: if it is an unhandled exception (so it is unexpected -> a bug) yes. Otherwise the task would catch it and handle it.

Comment: @SoMoS No, It will work with any PC with .NET Framework 4 (with KB2468871) installed

Comment: Hm, what you describe requires a FailFast as described in the answer. But that is rarely a good idea. Is it really necessary to exit *immediately*? That sounds like a bad architecture. Is there unsafe code involved that might corrupt state?

Comment: @usr: seems quite normal to me to crash the application when you have an unexpected exception, seems a best practice to avoid user data corruption. As far as I know this seems widely used approach (in line with recommendations like never catch Exception ,etc)

Comment: @SoMoS yeah you want to stop your work but why fail so abruptly? I usually let errors bubble up if I can't do something meaningful about them. Exceptions caused by bugs such as NRE's just bubble up and naturally end processing. They are being caught by a global logging handler (maybe to send an email) and *then* the app ends. Normal .NET control flow, no need for FailFast.

Comment: @usr: I completely agree with you but with the current scenario this will only happen when the GC tries to recollect the task which can happen several minutes latter after the exception happened. FailFast is not really an option for us. I think we will have to switch back to the ThreadPool.

Comment: @SoMoS on the thread-pool the exception will just be ignored. I think you should make sure that you observe the exception of all fire-and-forget tasks. Write yourself an extension method for task that can be used to very simply attach a logging continuation. Also, I'd say that fire and forget is very dangerous in general because the work is lost if the app shuts down (maybe for redeployment or reboot).

Comment: @SoMoS How are you registering your global event handlers?

Comment: @usr: sorry but the ThreadPool behaves as we expect and follows the normal exception scalation. Check the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found how to do it even when it is a bit complicated:

```
namespace ThreadExceptions
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        public static Task ObserveExceptions(this Task task)
        {
            return task.ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((w) =>
                {
                    if (t.Exception != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Exception ex in t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                        {
                            throw new TaskException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness);
        }
    }
}
```

This will make the application crash without waiting for the task. That's was I was looking for.

Comment: Where is TaskException class comes from? Was this your helper class?

Comment: Is a custom exception class with nothing special. Replace it with the exception you prefer

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting an old topic, but I'm trying to crash fire-and-forget tasks as well. I have a question: why use a ThreadPool? If very busy, the pool might delay your exception-throwing code for some time. Have you thought about launching a single, old-fashioned Thread with priority set to Highest? It seems like that would cut through the line faster, right?

Comment: Craeting a Thread is much slower than using the ThreadPool that has the Threads already created and waiting. That was the main reason to create the Pool.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution using [FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289240%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This method terminates the process without running any active
>   **try/finally blocks or finalizers**.

```
private void Test()
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Environment.FailFast("Test", new ApplicationException("Test"));
    });
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer but we need to hit our unhandled exception global handler to fire up all the process we do when we catch an application bug. I guess that this solution does not fires it.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own `Task` class which wraps the various `Task` methods that you want to use, and add the exception handling to it.

For example:

```
public static class TaskWithExceptionHandling
{
    public static Task StartNew(Action action)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);

        task.ContinueWith(exceptionHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        return task;
    }

    private static void exceptionHandler(Task task)
    {
        // Handle unhandled aggregate task exception from 'task.Exception' here.

        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + task.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);
    }
}
```

Which you would substitute for the `Task` class like so:

```
Task task = TaskWithExceptionHandling.StartNew(() =>
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Test exception");
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: He doesn't want an exception handler. He wants the application to crash. Your wrapper class would simply swallow the IOE.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The OP said in a comment *"if we have an unexpected exception (which means we have a bug, otherwise it is not unexpected) we want to crash the application and save the current state. To do that we use global handlers"*. So I am showing how he can call the global handlers when an unhandled task exception occurs.

Comment: I think the primary concern of the OP is not the global event handlers, its the immediate shutdown of the application. He doesn't want to wait for the finalizer to run.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It doesn't appear that he wants the immediate shutdown. He wants the global event handlers to run before shutting down; see his reply to another answer which suggests using FailFast: *"we need to hit our unhandled exception global handler to fire up all the process we do when we catch an application bug."*. Otherwise he could just call `FailFast()` where I put the comment "Handle unhandled aggregate task exception..."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion if any. We have global catchers set in the very beginning of the application start-up so we really prefer to use the standard .Net mechanism of escalating the exceptions. Matthew point is a good point anyway meaning that we can simulate that system by calling somehow the global handler and shutting down the application. Having said that I think we will switch back to the ThreadPool as it behaves as expected.