# Why is the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException does not trigger?

Tags: c#, debugging, task-parallel-library, task, unhandled-exception

I have an app targeting `.NET4` running on a `.NET4.6.1` machine with the following `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I then try to run the following expecting to see the message `Boom!: ....`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetupUnobservedTaskExceptionHandling();

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task started");
            var innerException = new InvalidOperationException("No way!");
            throw new ApplicationException("Ooops!", innerException);
        });

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // The task should be in faulted state before collection for the exception event to bubble up
    Console.WriteLine($"Task Status: {task.Status}");

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    GC.KeepAlive(task);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public static void SetupUnobservedTaskExceptionHandling()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Setting up unobserved task exception handling...");
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Boooom!: {0}", args);
    };
    Console.WriteLine("Set up unobserved task exception handling.");
}
```

But the event is never triggered regardless of a build type of `Debug` or `Release`. What is going on?

Comment: Remove that `GC.KeepAlive(task);`

Comment: Also must use Release because Debug extends local var lifetimes for debuggability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achievethe expected behavior you can follow the comments above and remove `GC.KeepAlive(task)` while using Release

or

you can set `task = null;` before calling `GC.Collect();` to ensure that task is collected.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284286/5246145) you can find another related answer that maybe add some more detail.