# ASP.NET Core IApplicationBuilder `Use` Does Not Allow Exception Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-7.0

Please observe this ASP.NET Core 7 Program.cs file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var app = builder.Build();

        int mode = 1;//1, 2, 3, or 4

        if (mode == 1)
        {
            app.Use(async (HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1);
                throw new InvalidOperationException();//Not caught by exception helper
            });
        }

        if (mode == 2)
        {
            app.Use((HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) =>
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();//Caught by exception helper
            });
        }

        if (mode == 3)
        {
            app.Run((HttpContext context) =>
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();//Caught by exception helper
            });
        }

        if (mode == 4)
        {
            app.MapGet("/", () =>
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();//Caught by exception helper
            });
        }

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Depending on the value of `mode` (which can be 1, 2, 3, or 4), the pipeline will be built differently. Notice that if it is set to 1 (utilizing the `Use (async)` method), an exception is "silently" thrown while debugging, resulting in the *exception page* in the browser. If `mode` is 2, 3, or 4 (utilizing either `Use(sync)`, `Run`, or `MapGet`), the *exception helper* appears.

The absence of the exception helper means that exceptions thrown during these calls result in the ASP.NET Core exception page, and while the exception page is somewhat helpful, it's much more helpful to see the exception helper indicate exactly when and where the exception was thrown while freezing the program in that moment so I can examine local variables, watches, etc.

Why does the exception helper not show in mode 1 (using `Use`)? Is there any way to make the exception helper show with `Use`? It's so odd the exception helper is shown with the sync version of `Use` but not with the async version. Thank you.

## Update 1

Using Exception Settings in Visual Studio, I could tell Visual Studio to break always on all exceptions. And that sort of works until something like this happens:

```
app.Use(async (HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    try
    {
        File.ReadAllText("Missing File.txt");
        //Exception handler opens here, even though it normally wouldn't.
        //The exception is user handled, so I want to ignore it.
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        //handle missing file
    }
});
```

How can I break on exceptions which are not user handled (and ignore the user-handled ones)?

Answer (score 1):

"Why does the exception helper not show in mode 1 (using Use)?" As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966522/7450780) and more on the  [Explanation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html#exceptions)

> The state machine for async methods will capture exceptions from your
> code and place them on the returned task. Without the async keyword,
> the exception is raised directly rather than going on the task.
>
> The expected asynchronous semantics are that exceptions are placed on
> the returned task. Since the returned task represents the execution of
> the method, if that execution of that method is terminated by an
> exception, then the natural representation of that scenario is a
> faulted task.

"Is there any way to make the exception helper show with `Use`?" Yes depending on your IDE,Im using `VS 2022` and I'm able to load the exception helper whenever that exception is raised and that's through the [Exception settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022).

> The debugger can break execution at the point where an exception is
> thrown, so you may examine the exception before a handler is invoked.

**ALTERNATIVE**

Another option as opposed to the Exception settings one is to then find a way to await the task executed in the async lambda expression.
The Task created in there is facing the exception and getting faulted.

```
if (mode == 1)
    {
            app.Use((HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) =>
            {
                 var task =  GetAsyncException(context,next);
                 task.Wait();
                 return task;
            });
    }
```

And the async method `GetAsyncException`:

```
 public static async Task GetAsyncException(HttpContext context,RequestDelegate next)
  {
            await Task.Delay(1);
            throw new InvalidOperationException(); // Not caught by exception helper
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I've tried this strategy before, and it causes all user-handled exceptions to be caught in the exception helper, which is not desirable. Is there any way to prevent that? I've updated my question.

Comment: If set Yes ,the exception Helper will raise for all exceptions, Made an edit as well, Another alternative is to await the completion of that task getting the exception in your async lambda expression.

Comment: Since I want to take advantage of async/await, I don't want to use `Task.Wait()`. But thank you anyway.