Objective benefit of static local function that's only called once?
Recently I was looking at the source code of Stream.CopyToAsync, which is available here on github.
The author first validates the parameters and then calls a static local function that does the actual processing. I find static local functions to be quite useful when I need to reuse a functionality, but don't wan't to add yet another private method.
But in Stream.CopyToAsync the static local function is called just once at the very end of the declaring method. I don't see any benefit here.
=> Is there any objective benefit (i.e. performance, security, better compiler optimizations, memory usage, ...) to use a static local function here?
Please note that I'm not asking about readability, because that's somewhat opinionated.
Code:
public virtual Task CopyToAsync(Stream destination, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ValidateCopyToArguments(destination, bufferSize);
    if (!CanRead)
    {
        if (CanWrite)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_UnreadableStream();
        }

        ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException_StreamClosed(GetType().Name);
    }

    return Core(this, destination, bufferSize, cancellationToken);

    static async Task Core(Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(bufferSize);
        try
        {
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(new Memory<byte>(buffer), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
            {
                await destination.WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(buffer, 0, bytesRead), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
        }
    }
}

Which is in my opinion exactly the same as without a static local function:
public virtual async Task CopyToAsync(Stream destination, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ValidateCopyToArguments(destination, bufferSize);
    if (!CanRead)
    {
        if (CanWrite)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_UnreadableStream();
        }

        ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException_StreamClosed(GetType().Name);
    }

    // return Core(this, destination, bufferSize, cancellationToken);

    byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(bufferSize);
    try
    {
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = await this.ReadAsync(new Memory<byte>(buffer), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
        {
            await destination.WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(buffer, 0, bytesRead), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
    }
}


Exceptions thrown in an async method will be wrapped up in the Task. The purpose of the local function might be to allow exceptions to be thrown in a non-async method, so they are thrown immediately. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69966157/5133585

SonarLint has even a rule for this case - https://sonarsource.github.io/rspec/#/rspec/S4457/csharp

@Sweeper that's a good explanation. Could you please post this as answer, so I can accept it? :)
Also on closer inspection I noticed, that CopyToAsync is actually not async, which means, the method itself is not compiled to a state machine, rigth?

I simply accept static code for what it is: no other "object" dependencies; and when it makes sense, can easily be "moved" to another container / namespace. "Granularity". (I combine; refactor; combine; repeat).

Sweeper gave a good explanation in the comments, which I will summarize here.
Also this question and this microsoft devblog post and especially this blog post helped me understand the great idea behind this.
Key points:

The static local function Core encapsulates all async operations of Stream.CopyToAsync -> the compiler will transform Core to an async state machine.
Stream.CopyToAsync itself is not async and will not be transformed to a state machine.
If an exception is thrown during validation (befor the call to Core) the exception will directly be passed on to the caller.
Exceptions thrown in Core will only be passed to the caller when the resulting Task is awaited.

Minmalistic example, as of my understanding:
Task Foo(Argument arg)
{
    if(!arg.IsValid) throw new ArgumentException();

    return Core(arg);

    static async Task Core(Argument arg) { await SomeAsyncOperations(); }
}

async Task Bar(Argument arg)
{
    if(!arg.IsValid) throw new ArgumentException();

    await SomeAsyncOperations();   
}

// no difference in usage when awaited immediately

await Foo(invalidArg); // throws here
await Bar(invalidArg); // throws here

// big difference if awaited somewhere else (or not awaited at all)

var fooTask = Foo(invalidArg); // throws here (!)
await fooTask;

var barTask = Bar(invalidArg); // no throw here (!)
await barTask; // throws here


