# How to crash on unhandled Task exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

I'd like to properly understand the consequences of failing to observe an exception thrown on a `Task` used in a fire and forget manner without exception handling.

Here's an extract from CLR via C#, Third Edition by Jeffry Richter: "[...] when a `Task` object is garbage collected, its `Finalize` method checks to see if the `Task` experienced an unobserved exception; if it has, `Task`'s `Finalize` method throws [an exception]. Since you cannot catch an exception thrown by the CLR's finalizer thread, your process is terminated immediately."

I am writing some test code to bring about a termination but am unable to cause one.

Using the test code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284286/3051702), I am able to see the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` handler being called. However, if I comment out the event handler subscription, the exception appears to be swallowed and does not bring about termination of the program.

I've tried this using the .NET Framework on both versions 4 and 4.8 with a Release build.

How do I demonstrate that failing to observe an exception thrown on a `Task` does indeed cause a crash?

Comment: Are you sure you've *actually* been running on .NET 4, rather than just targeting .NET 4 but running on 4.5+? As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-6.0, you can configure this on a per-application basis in app.config, but the default is for it to *not* crash the app now.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet I think that's it. Adding `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>` does crash the program as expected.

Comment: Do you have time to post an answer here Jon?

Comment: No, you can add an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is correctly identified by Jon Skeet in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70346065/how-to-crash-on-unhandled-task-exception#comment124350854_70346065) to the original post.

The best resource I found concerning this topic is by [Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/).

tldr:
"To make it easier for developers to write asynchronous code based on Tasks, .NET 4.5 changes the default exception behavior for unobserved exceptions.  While unobserved exceptions will still cause the UnobservedTaskException event to be raised (not doing so would be a breaking change), the process will not crash by default.  Rather, the exception will end up getting eaten after the event is raised, regardless of whether an event handler observes the exception.  This behavior can be configured, though.  A new CLR configuration flag may be used to revert back to the crashing behavior of .NET 4, e.g."

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled=”true”/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This looks like a good reference, thanks. Referenced Jon's comment to the original post.