# How to catch an exception in a task?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

In the following example exception is not intercepted and the program keeps running as if nothing happened. Is there a global error handler that can intercept such exceptions?
Here's playground [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFsxg3).

**Config**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
  {
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
      try
      {
        Program.ThrowErrorInTask();
        Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Exception not caught");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
      }
    }
    static public void ThrowErrorInTask()
    {
      Task.Run(() =>
      {
        throw new Exception("Something happened");
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: `await` the task - that's the simplest option.

Comment: Is the task even started, or does the termination of the program kill the additional thread before it even begins to run?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, what if I don't have the right to modify `ThrowErrorInTask`?

Comment: Why can't you modify it?

Comment: [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-6.0) event would be raised when your fire and forget Task is collected by the GC and it failed with an exception.

Comment: @CompuChip, I added `Task.Delay(2000).Wait();`  (plenty of time to initiate another thread) and there's still no error.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, `ThrowErrorInTask` could be a method from 3rd party library.

Comment: Then I would say that third party library has a bug, either by mishandling exceptions, or not providing you a way to handle exceptions that result from using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `Task.Run` is not `await`ed that's why it is considered as a fire and forget task. The `Task` itself can not throw exception (it only populates its `Exception` property), the `await` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` can throw.

The `TaskScheduler` exposes an event called [UnobservedTaskException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-6.0), which is raised whenever your Task is collected by the GC and the Task is failed. The `UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs` exposes an `Exception` property which contains the unobserved exception.

For more details please check this SO thread: [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event handler never being triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284137/taskscheduler-unobservedtaskexception-event-handler-never-being-triggered).